# What type of sacred texts are in form of dialog between an expert (sage?) & a disciple?

Tags: scripture

Several years ago I read online that there are these texts in form of questions & answers, and I do not remember what are these kind of texts called. 
My memory told me it was called Upanishads but recently realized that's not correct.

Why I'm asking this - 
Years ago when I read about it, I had found several such texts online I found a really interesting one. Where the expert(teacher) was a being who lived outside of the space-time fabric, hence it wasn't affected by time. And in one of the answer in the text, it said -

**"I've seen events of Ramayana happening 14 times and Mahabharata 18 times, and mostly they always end up in the same way."**

Now I can not find anything online about it, hack I can't even find the name of category of such texts.
I've started to doubt my memory now. Is it an actual memory or just an old half remembered dream of reading something so sci-fi-esq & over time I started believing it's an actual memory.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about? or anything similar to this?
Or at least the name of category so that i can try to find more about it online.
Please help.

Comment: The bold text is possibly said by Kakabhushandi in **Yoga Vashishtha**..

Comment: Yes i believe that's it. Thank you so much for helping me out.
It was really bothering me.